# Como combinar os valores de duas colunas diferentes em uma só em PYTHON?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, planilha, columns

Estou em processo de automatização de planilhas em meu trabalho, porém estou com dificuldade para combinar duas colunas em uma nova.

O display:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso combinar a coluna NUM_SS e SEQ com um "-0" entre elas... as duas são do tipo int64, tentei assim:

`df['NEW_COLUMN'] = df['NUM_SS'] + '-0' + df['SEQ']`

A intenção é ter uma coluna "NEW_COLUMN" com o valor 96426-01 , por exemplo.

Porém me retorna o erro:

> UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('int64'), dtype('<U2')) -> None

Answer (score 2):

Ambas as colunas devem ser do tip `int`.

Veja abaixo como fazer:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [7,8,9]})

>>> df["A"] + df["B"]   # neste caso somando tipo int
0     8
1    10
2    12
dtype: int64

>>> df["A"].astype(str) + "-0-" + df["B"].astype(str)   # usando como str e concatenando
0    1-0-7
1    2-0-8
2    3-0-9
dtype: object
```

Comment: Para quem votou negativo, poderia dizer o motivo para que eu melhore a resposta?